# powershell cloudberry snap in Select-CloudFolder error : "Redirect location is empty"

Tags: powershell, cloudberry

I need to connect to my bucket via cloudberry powershell snap in. I go through these steps:

```
Set-CloudOption -ProxyAddress {muProxyAddress} -ProxyPort 80
$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -Key myKey -Secret mySecret
$source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -Path myBucketName/myFolderName
```

But I get this error:

```
Select-CloudFolder : Redirect location is empty
At line:1 char:17
+ $source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -Path myBucketName/myFolderName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Select-CloudFolder], Exception
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn.Commands.SelectCloudFolder
```

And this is what is written in log file:

2016-09-01 16:06:03,368 [S3] [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO - HEAD request, bucket: myBucketName, key: , version: 
2016-09-01 16:06:04,738 [Base] [Pipeline Execution Thread] INFO - MovedPermanently to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn
Set-CloudOption -ProxyAddress xxxx -ProxyPort xxxx -PathStyle Path
$key = "xxxx"
$secret = "xxxx"
$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -Key $key -Secret $secret
$source = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path TestAutoSync/backup
```

Comment: Happy it helps! Accept this as answer so other members can use this as the solution for similar cases.

Comment: For me the resolution was -PathStyle VHost as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41400287/368105